# Streaming Java Swing animation as video

Tags: java, swing, video-streaming

I have a desktop Java Swing application. It consists from a single window and visualizes some animation. 
I fully control the animation in `public void paintComponent(final Graphics g);`

How to make it possible to watch it remotely from a web browser as a video steaming?
What third party software do I need to create a video stream, transmit it, and view it?

Answer (score 2):

1. draw the painting of the `paintComponent(g)` into an `BufferedImage`
2. [Write the image using ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) in sequence, one after another
3. use [`FFMPEG`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images) to generate video from the image. I don't think you can stream online; writing image and streaming at the same time.